# Neural network with categorical variables (enum) as inputs

Tags: enums, neural-network

I'm trying to solve some machine-learning problems using neural networks, mostly with the `NEAT` evolution (NeuroEvolution of Augmented Topologies).

Some of my input variables are continuous, but some of them are of a categorical nature, like:

- Species: {Lion,Leopard,Tiger,Jaguar}
- Branches of Trade: {Health care,Insurances,Finance,IT,Advertising}

At first I wanted to model such a variable by mapping the categories to discrete numbers, like:

{Lion:1, Leopard:2, Tiger:3, Jaguar:4}

But I'm afraid this adds some kind of arbitrary topology on the variable. A Tiger is not the sum of a Lion and a Leopard.

**What approaches to this problem are usually employed?**

Comment: And what would be wrong if the network would learn that for inputs scaled in such manner a `Tiger` is a sum of a `Lion` and a `Leopard`? As long as it will achieve low approximation error you don't have to worry that the network doesn't really understand the semantics of your data - networks never "understand" anything. If your not comfortable with it, at first change each `Lion` to `X1` etc. or something even more abstract.

Comment: Thanks. The network can "understand" that the topology "does not mean anything", but this could be a huge learning effort when there are many categories. I was asking if there are better solutions.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no **good** solution, each leads to some kind of problems:

- Your solution is adding the topology, as you mentioned; it may not be that bad, as NN can fit arbitrary functions and represent "ifs", but in many cases it will (as NN are often falling into some local minima).
- You can encode your data in form of `is_categorical_feature_i_equal_j`, which won't induce any additional topology, but will grow the number of features quadratically. So instaed of "species" you get features "is_lion", "is_leopard", etc. and only one of them is equal `1` at the time
- in case of large amount of data as compared to the possible categorical values (for example you have 10000 od data points, and only 10 possible categorical values) one can also split the problem into 10 independent ones, each trained on one particular value (so we have "neural network for lions" "neural network for jaguars" etc.)

These two first approaches are to "extreme" cases - one is very computationally cheap, but can lead to high bias, while the second introduces much complexity, but should not influence the classification process itself. The last one is rarely usable (due to assumption of small number of categorical values) yet quite reasonable in terms of machine learning.

## Update

So many things changes in 8 years. Solution 2 is definitely the most popular one, and with growth of compute, wide adoption of neural networks, and support of sparse inputs, the costs is now negliegiable