# String input in Neural Network Matlab

Tags: string, matlab, input, neural-network

I'm trying to use the neural network in Matlab to predict if a produced batch is going to pass some test. For doing so I have the input variables (temperature, kilograms of colorant used, material etc)and the output, a numerical value that tells me how good it is. First I want to train the network and then use it to predict the result for new batches.

The problem arises when I need to enter the material, color etc of the batch, because those are strings and they have to stay like that, in other words, they are groups and not continuous values. 
I read that it is possible to change the words to their numerical representation, but that it will give an order based on how close are the numbers, and that does not represent how related are the word in real life. For example, the batches that are made of cotton are better than those made of silk, and I want to have that observation in the neural network.

Is it possible to let the string a string, or to let the groups apart?

Comment: There is no good solution. Possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18825213/neural-network-with-categorical-variables-enum-as-inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to note, is that you should not map groups to continous numbers in such cases i.e not (1=silk, 2=cotton etc). The method of choice here is one-hot bag of features, (i.e. 1 0 0 - silk, 0 1 0 - cotton 0 0 1 - some other material) - so you have one binary feature for each possible value of material. This way, input would not imply some arbitry connection between group values.

You can also try, after doing this, putting  one additional hidden layer on top of each group input, while disconnecting input of other features from this layer. Provided that you have enough training examples, such intermidiate hidden layers can learn better representation, where similar group members are close to each other. This was demonstrated in [now classical work](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~vincentp/ift3395/lectures/backprop_old.pdf) that introduced backpropagation itself. This may, or may not work better than fully connected network, depending on your data and task specifics.

In a similar way, it possible to learn numerical representations of words in vector space, so words that are semantically similar are mapped to vectors that are close to each other (by Euclidean or other metrics), but this is unlikely to be helpful in your case since general semantic similarity does not reflect unitility for testing batches, but can be useful for other tasks.

Finally there is a way to feed character strings into NN (this is also unuseful for your case, but since you asked about strings, I mention it for completeness). This is done by encoding characters using one-hot representations (as described above), and used mainly for text processing tasks.